# How to use mlflow spark udf with image?

Tags: tensorflow, apache-spark, mlflow

I have trained a model via tensorflow using mnist data

```
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
```

Now I am trying to predict on `x_test` with shape `(10000, 28, 28)`

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri="my_run_uri", result_type='double')

num_rows = 10000
arr = map(lambda x: (Vectors.dense(x), ), x_test.reshape(num_rows, -1))
df = spark.createDataFrame(arr, ["features"])
```

But if I call

```
output = df.withColumn('predictions', loaded_model(struct(*map(col, df.columns))))
```

I run into

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported data type: struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;
```

What does this error mean?